# Jquery addClass after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering, why jQuery code is executed `addClass` function after page render.

I have some element (`h1`) positioned absolute.This element has rule:

```
left: 60%;
```

And simple JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').find('header').find('h1').addClass('move');
})
```

CSS:

```
.move {
    left: 40%
}
```

Now, question: why on page loads, `h1` element is first on 60% left, but second after load, it moves to left by 40% thanks to `move` class.
This effect looks bad, as `h1` element has now replace effect visible on page...

I want to have this element at left 40% so user can't see "move effect".

Regards,
Marek.

Comment: Why are you then setting as element style `left: 60%` and not directly `left: 40%`???

Comment: For some pages this should have 60% and as i cant edit html, i need to move element using JS for some other pages.

Comment: So this should be set before rendering page client side, meaning it should be done server side.

Comment: If you are able to edit css simply use more specific selector below `#test header h1 {left: 60%;}`

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of `$(document).ready()`; is that it executes **after** the page is rendered. If you don't want the user to see a change, you need to either set the style in CSS or only show the element after you've set the Class in JS.

Comment: right, i will first hide element, and them add class and show. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This addClass function is called after page render because you have written it inside document.ready(). Instead write it in open script block to load it just after html.

Answer (score 1):

The ready event occurs when the **DOM (document object model)** has been loaded.

Because this event occurs **after** the document is **ready**, it is a good place to have all other jQuery events and functions.

The **ready()** method specifies what happens when a ready event occurs.

so you have to set the style css

Answer (score -1):

Use `$(document).load(function() { // your code });` instead of document ready function.